# ¿Por qué no se retorna el modelo a la vista cuando retorno hacia la misma vista?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo un AccessController que tiene dos ActionResult, Login() y Entrar(). El Login() es el HttpGet y al retornar le paso un modelo a la vista. El Entrar() es el HttpPost y si el modelo que recibe de la vista no es valido, entonces retorno `return View("Login");`. El problema es que el modelo que paso a la vista es nulo cuando retorno `return View("Login");`. Cuando la vista se carga la primera vez, el modelo se carga perfectamente, pero al mandar a mostrar la vista de nuevo cuando el modelo del HttpPost no es valido entonces me dice que el modelo es nulo. Este es el form de la vista:

```
<form action="Entrar" method="post">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-8 text-center">
        <h5 id="titulo">Entrar al Sistema</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" id="usuario" class="form-control w-75" placeholder="Digite su Usuario" minlength="8" required>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="contrasena" class="form-control w-75 mt-3" placeholder="Digite su Contraseña" minlength="8" required>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    <div class="col-8 d-flex flex-column align-items-center">
        <select name="empresa" id="selectEmpresa" class="btn-secondary colorSelectEmpresa w-75 py-2 mt-3">
            @{
                WebAppInventariosTNRD.Models.ListViewModels.AllListViewModels oLista = new WebAppInventariosTNRD.Models.ListViewModels.AllListViewModels();
                oLista = Model;
                int contador = 1;
                foreach (var oElemento in oLista.ListaDeEmpresasList)
                {
                    if (contador == 1)
                    {
                        <option value="@contador" selected class="bg-light text-dark">@oElemento.NombreEmpresa</option>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <option value="@contador" class="bg-light text-dark">@oElemento.NombreEmpresa</option>
                    }
                    contador++;
                }
            }
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success py-2 px-3 mt-3">Iniciar Sesión</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2"></div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Y este el ActionResult que dirige hacia esa vista:

```
        public ActionResult Login()
    {
        AllListViewModels allListViewModels = new AllListViewModels();
        allListViewModels.ListaDeEmpresasList = null;

        using (InventarioTNRDEntities db = new InventarioTNRDEntities()) 
        {
            allListViewModels.ListaDeEmpresasList = (from _emp in db.Empresa
                                                    select new ListaDeEmpresasListViewModel
                                                    {
                                                        NumeroEmpresa = _emp.IdEmpresa,
                                                        NombreEmpresa = _emp.NombreEmpresa
                                                    }).OrderBy(n => n.NumeroEmpresa).ToList();
        }
        return View(allListViewModels);
    }
```

Este es el Action Entrar()

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Entrar(string usuario, string password, string empresa)
{
    try
    {
        using (InventarioTNRDEntities db = new InventarioTNRDEntities())
        {
            var lst = from _empresa in db.Empresa
                      join _ctlgUsuarios in db.CatalogoUsuarios
                      on _empresa.IDcatalogoUsuarios equals _ctlgUsuarios.IDcatalogoUsuarios
                      join _users in db.Usuarios
                      on _ctlgUsuarios.IDcatalogoUsuarios equals _users.IDcatalogoUsuarios
                      where _users.NombreUsuario == usuario && _users.Password == password && _empresa.Numero.ToString() == empresa
                      select _users;

            var IdEmpresa = from _empresa in db.Empresa
                            where _empresa.Numero.ToString() == empresa
                            select _empresa.IdEmpresa;

            if (lst.Count() > 0)
            {
                Usuarios oUser = lst.First();
                Session["User"] = oUser;
                Session["Empresa"] = IdEmpresa.First();
                Session["NotificarAccion"] = "0";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Main");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["NotificacionIndex"] = "2";
                ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Los datos ingresados no son correctos.";
                return View("Login");
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ViewData["NotificacionIndex"] = "3";
        ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Error inesperado en tiempo de ejecución! " + ex.Message;
        return View("Login");
    }
}
```

El error es: oLista was null. Justo al intentar iterarlo en el foreach en la vista, cabe mencionar que en modo debug me di cuenta que cuando mando a mostrar la vista de nuevo, no esta entrando al codigo de la vista Login(), pero si la muestra hasta dar el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el metodo de Login mandas la vista y el modelo, pero en el metodo entrar solo mandas la vista sin el modelo y la vista necesita ese modelo para rellenar la info que estas utilizando. Porque mejor no haces un redirect al metodo login cuando el usuario falle acceder?

Comment: "Por que no mejor haces ..." suena mas a un comentario que a una respuesta

Answer (score 0):

1. El código no esta completo, no puedo ver el método Entrar.
2. La manera de llenar el **select** no es correcto, requiere más código y puede estar generando el problema.

Sugerencia de como hacerlo:

1. [https://asp.mvc-tutorial.com/tag-helpers/the-select-tag-helper/][1]
2. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624034/select-tag-helper-in-asp-net-core-mvc]

Comment: Hola, he añadido el resto del código. Con respecto a los tag Helpers, están disponibles hasta .net core, y estoy trabajando MVC 5.

Comment: Lee [answer]. Evita responder si OP (autor de la publicación) no ha proveído información suficiente en la pregunta. Además, el contenido esencial de los enlaces debe ir _en la respuesta misma_. Piénsalo: si los enlaces llegan a caer, y un lector más adelante tiene un problema similar, ¿cómo sabrá qué contenían los enlaces?

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).